# Unable to cast object of type 'Sitecore.Web.SessionEndWorkerRequest'

Tags: solr, session-state, authentication, iis

For one of our current assignment, we are on:

- Sitecore 7.2 (rev. 141226)
- SOLR 4.6.1
- Sitecore Media Framework 4.1 - Brightcove
- Clay Tablet 3.10.1

Mentioning the details cause recently we introduced cores in SOLR for new website development, upgraded Brightcove and Clay Tablet. Hence not sure if anything from these activities is the culprit.

Following frequent exception started encountering recently in the log files:

> Exception: System.InvalidCastException Message: Unable to cast object
>   of type 'Sitecore.Web.SessionEndWorkerRequest' to type
>   'System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest'. Source: System.Web    at
>   System.Web.EtwTrace.Trace(EtwTraceType traceType, HttpWorkerRequest
>   workerRequest, String data1, String data2, String data3, String data4)
>   at
>   System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider.GetPropertyValuesFromDatabase(String
>   userName, SettingsPropertyValueCollection svc)    at
>   System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider.GetPropertyValues(SettingsContext
>   sc, SettingsPropertyCollection properties)    at
>   System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertiesFromProvider(SettingsProvider
>   provider)    at
>   System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertyValueByName(String
>   propertyName)    at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.get_Item(String
>   propertyName)    at System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase.GetInternal(String
>   propertyName)    at System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase.get_Item(String
>   propertyName)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.UserProfile.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__a()
>   at Sitecore.Support.Data.DataProviders.Retryer.Execute[T](Func`1
>   action, Action recover)

Followed by nested exceptions related to

> ERROR Call stack to retryer:     at
>   System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
>   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()    at
>   Sitecore.Support.Data.DataProviders.Retryer.Execute[T](Func`1 action,
>   Action recover)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.UserProfile.GetPropertyValueCore(String
>   propertyName)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.UserProfile.get_IsAdministrator()    at
>   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.SqlAuthorizationProvider.GetSpecialAccess(ISecurable
>   entity, Account account, AccessRight accessRight)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.SqlAuthorizationProvider.GetAccessCore(ISecurable
>   entity, Account account, AccessRight accessRight)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationProvider.GetAccess(ISecurable
>   entity, Account account, AccessRight accessRight)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationManager.GetAccess(ISecurable
>   entity, Account account, AccessRight accessRight)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationManager.IsAllowed(ISecurable
>   entity, AccessRight right, Account account)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAccess.CanRead()    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.ApplySecurity(Item item,
>   SecurityCheck securityCheck)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.GetItem(String itemPath, Language
>   language, Version version, Database database)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.VisitEnd.RunRules.Run(Database database) 
>   at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.VisitEndWorker.Helper.RaiseVisitEndForCurrentVisit()
>   at Sitecore.Analytics.VisitEndWorker.Helper.Process(Action
>   visitEndAction)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Web.Application.RaiseSessionEndEvent(HttpApplication context)
>   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[]
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InvokeMethodWithAssert(MethodInfo method,
>   Int32 paramCount, Object eventSource, EventArgs eventArgs)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ProcessSpecialRequest(HttpContext context,
>   MethodInfo method, Int32 paramCount, Object eventSource, EventArgs
>   eventArgs, HttpSessionState session)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.FireSessionOnEnd(HttpSessionState
>   session, Object eventSource, EventArgs eventArgs)    at
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionOnEndTargetWorkItem.RaiseOnEndCallback()
>   at System.Web.Util.WorkItem.CallCallbackWithAssert(WorkItemCallback
>   callback)    at
>   System.Web.Util.WorkItem.OnQueueUserWorkItemCompletion(Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()

Any guidance on finding the root cause is much appreciated.

P.S. Already gone through the answers to this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403207/sitecore-log-file-repeated-error) question, and the Analytics DB looks good.

Comment: I am new to this community. Seems someone down voted the question, would be great if downvote comes with a reason as a comment. I think with a genuine problem, this question follows all the rules to ask a good question.

Comment: Also unable to see an issue with this question in it's current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: Not sure if this is the exact root cause in your scenario.

But I googled the exception mentioned ("*System.Web.EtwTrace.Trace - Sitecore exception*") in the question above and it takes me to an Sitecore Knowledge base article below:

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/346314

The article takes you to a Microsoft page which talks about ***Disabling Failed Requests in IIS 7***.

I suggest to try the solutions by Microsoft and see if those resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it resolved the problem. Analyzing the root cause which actually enabled the tracing cause we dint enable it intentionally not sure if any steps from Brightcove or Clay Tablet upgrade forced that.